# Is there a way to save progress in a desktop application developed in python and pyqt5?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, progress-bar, desktop-application

Our application process a large audio file into number of smaller segemnts and displays it on a table in the GUI. The user can listen, label and comment on each segment in the table. So is there a way to save the progress that can be resumed from where the user left off with the last accessed row in the table?
For example in the table has 700 rows and the user has worked with 100 and closes the application, the next time they open the application they must be able to start working with the 101st row and the previous work must be saved.

Comment: Store the row number in a local file. You can get system paths where storing data using [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html), you might be interested in `AppLocalDataLocation`.

Comment: There isn't any built-in method for doing this, so you'll just need to decide for yourself what's relevant and save it in a configuration file. If you need to save qt types, [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) might be a good option.

Comment: @musicamante could you please help us with a sample code to help and guide us

Answer (score 0):

pickle (import pickle) allows you to write/read python objects and therefore save a progress status from one session to another.

Comment: Pickle works only for serializable objects.